# XNA Update and Screen Refresh

Tags: c#, xna, refresh, frame

I am actually creating a RPG Horror Game in XNA but something is bothering me, and I don't know how to call it. When my player moves, it is in fact the map that moves, the player stays in the middle of the screen. But when I have to move, the whole tileMap is re drawn. My problem is in that when it moves a lot, the screen is a little distorted, like if the bottom part couldn't follow the speed of the displacement, so the screen is like cut horizontaly. It's not a big problem, but still it annoys me since I want to do it as perfectly as possible.

Somebody told me that it was something with the *Vertical Syncing* and that I had to disable FixedTimeStep or something  and add a timer to my updates but I don't understand

Here is a [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/fxjxv0b4q66i8b3/A_Whisper_in_the_Wind_-_Demo.zip) to it, if some of you want to try and understand what I am trying to explain (in the second level, in the house when the lights are on you can see it good)

if somebody has an idea... That would be great

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you instead considered using a view matrix? This will simply displace where the map is drawn, but not where it physically is. Then all you have to do is move your player character and translate the view matrix.

There are already a few good resources on matrices in XNA, [like this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59301/xna-2d-camera-scrolling-why-use-matrix-transform). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309838/2299850) explains the whole idea quite well - it refers to transformation matrices 3D, but the same concepts apply to 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I make games using AS3 to export to flash and RPG Maker VX ACE usually if the scenary is large, the game can go slow. The key is disable all the efects or behaveur of elements than aren't visible in the screen.

I activate the behaveurs o visual effects when the element (npc or other entities) are visible, in others words, when are in the screen window.

Try to use triggers

Good luck